# How can I access the QUndoStack of a QTextDocument?

Tags: c++, qt, undo, undo-redo, qtextdocument

How can I access the `QUndoStack` of a `QTextDocument`?

(For example, I want to be able to add custom `QUndoCommand` objects to the document's undo stack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been reading the documentation and it doesn't seems to be a way to get the `QUndoStack` directly for the Widget.

Probably the only way is to create your own `QUndoStack` object and manually add the changes and then re-implement the `redo()` / `undo()` slots. I would have a look to the source code, you can probably get most of the code you need from there to store the changes in `QTextDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way :(

The way I used is modifying QTextDocument Class for my needs and then recompile Gui module.

The static linking is a good choice for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

## PySide2 solution: no reimplementation needed!

---

### Background and explanation (skip below for the code&instructions):

As others have said, indeed there seems to be no way to directly access the Undo stack as for May 2020. E.g. [This 2017 answer](https://forum.qt.io/topic/80969/accessing-textedit-s-undostack/8) by user mrjj at the Qt forum says that the stack lives inside `qtextdocument_p.cpp` and that **there isn't a way to access it through the interfaces**.

Instead, everyone suggests to **implement your own undo-able commands** and that it is a piece of cake, but I wasn't able to find such meaningful implementation. Also, the built-in functionality is well documented in the [QTextDocument docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtGui/QTextDocument.html?highlight=qtextdocument#detailed-description) and at least to me it doesn't look too straightforward to just reimplement:

> Undo/redo of operations performed on the document can be controlled using the setUndoRedoEnabled() function. The undo/redo system can be controlled by an editor widget through the undo() and redo() slots; the document also provides contentsChanged() , undoAvailable() , and redoAvailable() signals that inform connected editor widgets about the state of the undo/redo system. The following are the undo/redo operations of a QTextDocument :
>
> - Insertion or removal of characters. A sequence of insertions or removals within the same text block are regarded as a single undo/redo operation.
> - Insertion or removal of text blocks. Sequences of insertion or removals in a single operation (e.g., by selecting and then deleting text) are regarded as a single undo/redo operation.
> - Text character format changes.
> - Text block format changes.
> - Text block group format changes.

As we can see it integrates many different kinds of complex events and on the top of that it features command compressions. I personally disliked the idea of reimplementing that very much.

Ideally, we would access the stack through the API and we would be done! Hopefully this is supported at some point (*please* let me know in the comments if that is the case). **In this answer, I show a way to integrate the built-in QTextDocument Undo stack with minimal effort and retaining all its functionality**. I tried many different ways and I liked this one the best. Hope this helps!

---

### Code & Instructions

This code exemplifies the usage with a `QPlainTextEdit`, but you can reproduce it with other widgets. See the docstrings for explanations:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class TextDocumentUndoWrapperCommand(QtWidgets.QUndoCommand):
    """
    This command is a wrapper that simply uses the text document stack, but
    allows to register the action on a different stack for integration.
    """

    def __init__(self, txt_editor, parent=None):
        super().__init__("Text Document Action", parent)
        self.txt_editor = txt_editor

    def undo(self):
        self.txt_editor.document().undo()

    def redo(self):
        self.txt_editor.document().redo()


class TextEditor(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
"""
QTextDocument document has a really nice built-in undo stack, but
unfortunately it cannot be accessed or integrated with other undo stacks.
This class exemplifies such integration, as follows:

1. Important: we do NOT disable undo/redo functionality. We keep it on!
2. Every time that QTextDocument adds a Command to its own stack, we add
   a wrapper command to our own main stack
3. Every time the user sends an undo/redo event, we intercept it and send
   it through our wrapper command. This way we have effectively integrated
   the built-in undo stack into our own main stack.
"""

def __init__(self, parent=None, undo_stack=None):
    """
    """
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setLineWrapMode(self.WidgetWidth)  # matter of taste
    if undo_stack is not None:
        # if we provide a stack, integrate internal stack with it
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.undo_stack = undo_stack
        self.document().undoCommandAdded.connect(self.handle_undo_added)

def handle_undo_added(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    The key information is WHEN to create an undo command. Luckily,
    the QTextDocument provides us that information. That way, we can keep
    both undo stacks in perfect sync.
    """
    cmd = TextDocumentUndoWrapperCommand(self)
    self.undo_stack.push(cmd)

def eventFilter(self, obj, evt):
    """
    We didn't deactivate the undo functionality. We simply want to
    re-route it through our stack, which is synched with the built-in
    one.
    """
    if evt.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        if evt.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Undo):
            self.undo_stack.undo()
            return True
        if evt.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Redo):
            self.undo_stack.redo()
            return True
    return super().eventFilter(obj, evt)
```

The `TextEditor` can be then simply used as a regular widget. If we don't provide a stack to the constructor, the default built-in hidden stack will be used. If we provide one, the wrapper mechanism will integrate the hidden stack into the provided one.

---

*Note: I am not providing a solution for "just the QTextDocument" because I wasn't able to make the `eventFilter` work for it (I'm happy to hear about others' efforts). In any case, the QTextDocument is always inside any sort of parent widget/window, and then this logic should apply identically. There are plenty of forums asking for this functionality, and I think this was the best place to post this answer (let me know otherwise).*

Comment: Note: this will not work properly if the undo/redo is triggered by the context menu. A possible work around would be to override the `contextMenuEvent()`, get the default menu with [`createStandardContextMenu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#createStandardContextMenu), retrieve the undo/redo actions with `findChild()` using their object name (`edit-undo` and `edit-redo`), disconnect their `triggered` signals and connect them with the related slots of the custom undo stack.

Comment: Dear @musicamante, thanks for the valuable remark and suggested fix! Indeed, this solution is tailored for simple apps with simple undo/redo stack architecture. In any case, feel free to use/share my code in your own improved solution if you wish to.